# Given a circle, its diameter and an external point, use a straightedge to draw a line through the point and perpendicular to the diameter

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

Some time back I saw the following problem which originated in Russia:

> You are given a circle, its diameter and an external point not on the diameter (A, B and P in the diagram below). Using only a straightedge, construct a line through the point that is perpendicular to the diameter. Prove that the constructed line is indeed perpendicular.

Consider only the case where the perpendicular line meets the diametral line at a point Q that is outside the circle.

[image]

Comment: What is your question?  Are you asking for the construction or the proof?

Comment: Not even compass?

Comment: Both the construction and the proof are needed. No compass is allowed as it would make the contruction too easy (draw a circle through P cutting the diametral line at points C, D, then bisect CD).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call A' the intersection of the circle with AP
Call B' the intersection of the circle with BP
Call P' the intersection of A'B and AB'

Then PP' is perpendicular to AB

[image]

Now, the proof :

You have that :

- The triangle AA'B is a right triangle because it's a triangle inscribed in a circle with one of its side as a diameter.
- The triangle AB'B is a right triangle because it's a triangle inscribed in a circle with one of its side as a diameter.

This gives you that, for the triangle APP',

- PB' is the altitude from the vertex P
- P'A' is the altitude from the vertex P'

So B, the intersection of PB' and P'A', is the orthocentre.

It follow that AB is the altitude from the vertex A, hence AB and PP' are perpendicular

Comment: I suck on this kind of problem, but I'm always amazed with the solutions.

Comment: A very slick proof. (You may just want to remark that A'B and AB' cannot be parallel, so the construction is possible).